# Problems in trying to prove non-duplicate-element sequence in Dafny

Tags: sequence, dafny

Suppose we have a sequence s, and all of the elements are different from others. I describe this property as follow

```
predicate all_element_different(s: seq<int>)
{
  forall i,j :: 0 <= i < j < |s| ==> s[i] != s[j]
}
```

Of course, another equivalent way is

```
forall i,j :: 0 <= i < |s| && 0 <= j < |s| && i != j ==> s[i] != s[j]
```

So I write a lemma here

```
lemma different_properties(s: seq<int>)
  requires all_element_different(s)
  ensures forall i,j :: 0 <= i < |s| && 0 <= j < |s| && i != j ==> s[i] != s[j]
{
}
```

For some reason, I need to sort this sequence, and I wanna get another new sequence rather than directly modify the old one. Something like

```
function insertionSort(s: seq<int>): (r: seq<int>)
  ensures multiset(s) == multiset(r)
  ensures sorted(r)
  ensures forall x :: x in s ==> x in r
  ensures |s| == |r|
```

Just ignore the implemention of `insertionSort`. Anyway, finally we get another sequence `r`, with such properties hold:

```
  var r := insertionSort(s);
  assert multiset(s) == multiset(r);
  assert |s| == |r|;
  //assert sorted(r); This property is not used here
  assert forall x :: x in s ==> x in r;
  assert all_element_different(s);
```

Obviously, the predicate `all_element_different(r)` should hold, but I could not prove it. I tried to extract the process:

```
lemma sequence_properties(s: seq<int>, r: seq<int>)
  requires multiset(s) == multiset(r)
  requires |s| == |r|
  requires all_element_different(s)
  ensures all_element_different(r)
{
}
```

Anyone have some ideas for proof of this lemma?

================================================

**New method inspired from @Divyanshu Ranjan**

Before I asked this question, I have been exploring using multiplicity to finish the proof. Trivially this lemma holds

```
lemma equivalence(s: seq<int>)
  ensures UniqueElements(s) <==> forall k :: k in multiset(s) ==> multiset(s)[k] == 1
```

But I had some problems of its proof. Now using contradiction I finish it.

```
lemma UniqueMultiSet(s: seq<int>, r: seq<int>)
  requires UniqueElements(s)
  requires |s| == |r|
  requires multiset(s) == multiset(r)
  ensures UniqueElements(r)
{
  equivalence(s);
  equivalence(r);
}

lemma unique_elements_imply_multiplicity_equals_1(s: seq<int>)
  requires UniqueElements(s)
  ensures forall k :: k in multiset(s) ==> multiset(s)[k] == 1
{
  var ms := multiset(s);
  if !(forall k :: k in ms ==> ms[k] == 1)
  {
    var k :| k in ms && ms[k] > 1;
    var i :| 0 < i < |s|;
    var left := s[..i];
    var right := s[i..];
    assert s == left+right;
    // assert multiset(s) == multiset(left) + multiset(right);
    // assert multiset(s)[k] == multiset(left)[k] + multiset(right)[k];
    if k in left && k in right
    {
      assert !UniqueElements(s);
    } else if k in left && k !in right
    {
      unique_elements_imply_multiplicity_equals_1(left);
    } else if k !in left && k in right
    {
      unique_elements_imply_multiplicity_equals_1(right);
    }else
    {
      assert k !in multiset(s);
    }
  }
}

lemma multiplicity_equals_1_imply_unique_elements(s: seq<int>)
  requires forall k :: k in multiset(s) ==> multiset(s)[k] == 1
  ensures UniqueElements(s)
{
  if(!UniqueElements(s))
  {
    var i, j, k :| 0 <= i < j < |s| && s[i] == s[j] == k;
    var left := s[..i+1];
    var right := s[i+1..];
    assert s == left + right;
    assert j >= i+1;
    assert k in left && k in right;
    assert multiset(s)[k] >= 2;
  }
}

lemma equivalence(s: seq<int>)
  ensures UniqueElements(s) <==> forall k :: k in multiset(s) ==> multiset(s)[k] == 1
{
  if(UniqueElements(s))
  {
    unique_elements_imply_multiplicity_equals_1(s);
  }
  if(forall k :: k in multiset(s) ==> multiset(s)[k] == 1)
  {
    multiplicity_equals_1_imply_unique_elements(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea behind below proof is following

1. If it is not case that all elements of sequence
   r are unique then there should exists indices m < n
   such that r[m] == r[n].
2. Next we try to pair up elements of sequence s (left) with
   element of sequence r (right) by equality.
3. To do that we find index ridx in r such r[ridx] equal
   to current element of s we are pairing.
4. Now if ridx happens to be n, then we can pair current
   element of s with r[m] as r[m] == r[n]
5. Effectively we are pairing up n distinct elements with
   n-1 elements.
6. We do some index shifting to convince dafny that we
   indeed pairing with n-1 elements on right side of
   matching.
7. By pigeonhole two elements of left should pair up with
   same element on right.
8. This means those two elements are equal but that is not
   possible as all elements are distinct on left side.
9. Our assumption is wrong and all elements on right side
   are distinct.

---

```
predicate UniqueElements(s: seq<int>)
{
  forall i, j :: 0 <= i < j < |s| ==> s[i] != s[j]
}

lemma pigeonhole(m : int, n: int, f : int -> int)
  requires 0 <= m < n
  requires forall i :: 0 <= i < n ==> 0 <= f(i) < m
  ensures exists j, k :: (0 <= j < k < n) && f(j) == f(k)
{
  if m <= 0 {
    assert 0 <= f(0) < 0;
  }
  else {
    var i : int := 0;
    while i < n
      invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i ==> 0 <= f(k) < m - 1
      invariant i <= n
    {
      if f(i) == m-1 {
        var j : int := i + 1;
        while j < n
          invariant forall k :: i < k < j ==> 0 <= f(k) < m - 1
        {
          if f(j) == m-1 { return; }
            j := j + 1;
        }
        var g : int -> int := x => if x < i then f(x) else f(x+1);
        pigeonhole(m-1, n-1, g);
        return;
      }
      i := i + 1;
    }
    pigeonhole(m-1, n, f);
  }
}


lemma UniqueMultiSet(s: seq<int>, r: seq<int>)
  requires UniqueElements(s)
  requires |s| == |r|
  requires multiset(s) == multiset(r)
  ensures UniqueElements(r)
{
  assert |multiset(s)| == |multiset(r)|;
  if !UniqueElements(r){
    var m, n :| 0 <= m < n < |r| && r[m] == r[n];
    forall idx | 0 <= idx < |s| ensures exists ridx :: 0 <= ridx < |r| && r[ridx] == s[idx]
    {
      assert s[idx] in multiset(r);
    }
    var f : int -> int :=
      x => if 0 <= x < |s|
           then
              var idx :| 0 <= idx < |r| && r[idx] == s[x];
              if idx < n then idx else if idx == n then m else idx - 1
           else -1;
    pigeonhole(|s|-1, |s|, f);
    var k, l :| 0 <= k < l < |s| && f(k) == f(l);
    assert s[k] == s[l];
  }
}
```

Comment: Very grateful for this answer! Really fantastic idea! I tested it and totally correct. But I think as a dafny freshhand I should first spend some time understanding it.

Comment: I found a new intuitive way to prove the lemma, inspired from your idea. By the way, the use of pigeonhole is quite exquisite

Comment: I see your new proof now. Thanks for posting